# Using named range between two excel files

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two excel files. My named range data is located in file 1, and the result should be retrieved from file 2.

How do I link named range from file 1 to file 2 using the equation below?

`'2015'!$B$2:$B$19` = should be link to the name range "kshc2013D)

`'2015'!$A$2:$A$19` = should be link to the name range "kshc2013A)

`=SUMPRODUCT(('2015'!$B$2:$B$19=Count!A2)*('2015'!$A$2:$A$19=1))`

Comment: Different workbooks? Not worksheets? You need to include the workbook as a full file path `[c:\\my\file\excel.xls]Sheet1!kshc2013D`

Comment: do I need to manually type the link in the formula?

Comment: If you use the formula builder you should be able to click it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to reference a different work*book*, not work*sheet* you need to include the file location in the formula [kb](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-an-external-reference-link-to-a-cell--range-in-another-workbook-c98d1803-dd75-4668-ac6a-d7cca2a9b95f). e.g.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(([C:\my\files\file1.xls]2015!kshc2013D=[filepath]count!A2)*([C:\my\files]file2.xls2015!kshc2013A))
```